# calculate each row based on another table spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, join

I have a requirement where i need to calculate a column in my data frame. For each row of large dataframe i need to compare ***from and to*** with another  data frames ***flag*** and the ***date*** to calculate a new  column.

Basically the second table is a look up table which needs to be used to perform my calculation. I can see a lot of shuffles happening which inturn affects the jobs performance.
For Eg :
Large_DF

+------+----------+----------+

|  Loc |     From |To        |

+------+----------+----------+

|     A|2016-03-31|2016-03-31|
|     A|2016-02-28|2016-02-30|
|     A|2016-01-31|2016-02-11|
|     B|2014-12-31|2015-01-10|
+------+----------+----------+

+------+----------+----------+

|  Loc |     Date |Flag      |

+------+----------+----------+

|     A|2016-03-31|Yes       |
|     A|2016-02-11|NO        |
|     A|2016-02-11|Yes       |
|     B|2015-01-10|NO        |
+------+----------+----------+

I am planning to Join the large table on the Loc. The look uptable doesnt get updated and it is small.  Any suggestions on how to perform this operation in a optimal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hint to Spark SQL that a given DF should be broadcast for join by calling broadcast on the DataFrame before joining it, e.g.,

```
df1.join(broadcast(df2),"key")
```

The broadcast table is the small one.

That said, are you sure join condition is ok?

Comment: I think there is a problem with join condition. I am actually calculating the working days. In the small dataset for each Loc there will be 365 days with flags for holiday. So when i do the join it is skewing i guess. Initially i thought i could create UDF but itseems it is not possible to access the small dataframe inside the UDF.
Any Suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: join is the way to go

Comment: So what is the question then? I think the original question was answered. Skewness will not play a role in the join.

Comment: Can i use the select query inside a where clause in spark sql?

Comment: sub select is possible

Comment: But when i use it i am getting "Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate". Any idea why?

Comment: Thank you i have posted a new question with the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004938/correlated-column-is-not-allowed-in-a-non-equality-predicate

Comment: u have posted a new question I think

Comment: will look at that

Comment: Yes. I have attached the link with my previous comment