# Correlated sub query column in SPARK SQL is not allowed as part of a non-equality predicate

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am tryng to write a subquery in where clause like below. But i am getting 
***"Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate:"***

```
SELECT *, 
   holidays 
      FROM   ( 
          SELECT *, 
                 s.holidays, 
                 s.entity 
          FROM   transit_t tt 
          WHERE  ( 
                        SELECT Count(thedate) AS holidays 
                        FROM   fact_ent_rt 
                        WHERE  entity=tt.awborigin 
                        AND    ( 
                                      Substring(thedate,1,10)) BETWEEN (Substring(awbpickupdate,1,10)) AND    (
                                      Substring(deliverydate,1,10)) 
                        AND    ( 
                                      nholidayflag = true 
                               OR     weekendflag = true))) s
```

Any issues with this query. because i thought spark >2.0 supported subqueries in where clause. any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

The Input will be pick up date and delivery date from transit table. We need to find if there is a weekend falling between these dates(this data is available in fact_ent_rt ) and take the count of no of holidays.

The output i am getting is
    pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate:\nAggregate

Sample inputs:

Input 1:
    +---------++-------------------+-------------------+

```
|AWBOrigin||      AWBPickupDate|       DeliveryDate|

+---------++-------------------+-------------------+

|      LON||2018-09-01 08:52:00|2018-09-12 13:57:00|
|      DHA||2018-09-04 11:47:00|2018-09-08 07:30:00|
|      NIC||2009-01-01 01:47:00|2009-01-09 11:37:00
+---------+-----------+-----------------------------
```

Input 2 (fact_ent)

```
------+-------------------+-----------+------------

 Entity|            TheDate|WeekendFlag|NHolidayFlag

 ------+-------------------+-----------+------------

NIC|2009-01-01 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-02 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-03 00:00:00|       True|       False
NIC|2009-01-04 00:00:00|       True|       False
NIC|2009-01-05 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-06 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-07 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-08 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-09 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-10 00:00:00|       True|       False
NIC|2009-01-11 00:00:00|       True|       False
NIC|2009-01-12 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-13 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-14 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-15 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-16 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-17 00:00:00|       True|       False
NIC|2009-01-18 00:00:00|       True|       False
NIC|2009-01-19 00:00:00|      False|       False
NIC|2009-01-20 00:00:00|      False|       False
------+-------------------+-----------+------------
```

expectede Output

```
 +---------++-------------------+-------------------+

|AWBOrigin||      AWBPickupDate|       DeliveryDate| Holidays

+---------++-------------------+-------------------+

|      LON||2018-09-01 08:52:00|2018-09-12 13:57:00|  NA
|      DHA||2018-09-04 11:47:00|2018-09-08 07:30:00|  NA
|      NIC||2009-01-01 01:47:00|2009-01-09 11:37:00|  2
+---------+-----------+-----------------------------
```

Comment: Can only use equality currently. Need to show inputs and outputs to make it happen.

Comment: The idea is for each origin i have to find correspoding entity and its holiday data. and take the count back to perform some processing

Comment: also there should be 3 inputs

Comment: I need the input labelled correctly and then I can this afternoon provide an alternative SQL approach

Comment: I think the inputs are labelled correctly.Input is AWBOrigin||      AWBPickupDate|       DeliveryDate and lookup table is fct_ent.

Comment: Please edit correctly, that helps us and gets u into the groove here

Comment: Your out is unclear and input not representative enough. 3 outputs but only one for  input being NIC.

Comment: So if there is a NIC in the first table we have to find the corresponding NIC in the second table and get the Holidays flags count. AWB Origin and ENtty are the matching coliumns between both the tables. In the ouput i want all colimns of the first table and only count of holidays present in the second table for the particular AWBOrigin

Comment: Show graphically and representable - you need more variance and less occurrences. Remotely as we are that is the only way we can work as this is a fiddly topic

Comment: I get many variations of correlated sub query working, some not, so it may well be a case of another approach will suffice but the data is important to understand any alternative.

Comment: Sorry i missedyour comments. Basically between the Pick up and delivery date is there are any holidays i need to get the number of holidays which is present in the second input table. The first table and second table will have AWBORigin and ENtity as the common columns

Comment: For simplicity purpose i am giving the data for NIC. For eg. in INPUT1 the AWBOrigin is NIC. So in the INPUT 2 table there might be other Entities(AWBOrigin in Input 1). But we have to get the data presetn for NIC. In the input 2 table it will contain row for all dys of the year with Holiday and Weekend Flg for each entity. So based on the first tables AWBOrigin we need to get all the rows with all dates for the year and then for dates between pick up and delivery we need to find how many days have weekend and holiday flags to be to True. In our case it is 2.

Comment: How do you get 2?

Comment: If you look at Input 1 for NIC the pick up date is 2009-01-01 and deliverydate is 2009-01-09. In the Inpit 2 for NIC compare the date range between the pick up and delivery with TheDate column,  there are only two weekend or holiday flags with true. Therefore we get 2.

Comment: ok. what if holiday and weekend on same day? looking now at solution. you can use broadcast as in previous question.

Comment: Only one day will be counted if holiday and weekend fall on the same day. Can you elaborate on the boradcast

Comment: ok. cool as I thought

Comment: I just checked the rpevious solution which you had suggested. I need to have the conditions which i have given in the above SQL as well. Thank you very much for taking your time as i was breaking my head over this for the past couple of days.

Comment: working on it, in simplified format

Comment: Thank You Very much... I was just thinking is it possible to write a UDF for this or broadcast is the better option? Just wanted to see what you thought Thanks

Comment: Try and do things easier...

Comment: I _think_ this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256127/spark-sql-error-when-running-correlated-subquery/52256648. But I didn't really know what I was doing when I correctly answered that one, and this is more complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with SCALA so you will need to convert but in a far easier way I think. I added a key and did at key level, you can adapt and aggr that out. But principle is far simpler. No correlated sub queries required. Just relational calculus. Used number for dates, etc.

```
// SCALA 
// Slightly ambiguous on hols vs. weekend, as you stated treated as 1

import spark.implicits._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dfE = Seq( 
              ("NIC", 1, false, false),
              ("NIC", 2, false, false),
              ("NIC", 3, true, false),
              ("NIC", 4, true, true),
              ("NIC", 5, false, false),
              ("NIC", 6, false, false),
              ("XYZ", 1, false, true)
              ).toDF("e","d","w", "h")
 //dfE.show(false)

 val dfE2 = dfE.withColumn("wh", when ($"w" or $"h", 1) otherwise (0)).drop("w").drop("h")
 //dfE2.show()

//Assuming more dfD's can exist
val dfD = Seq( 
              ("NIC", 1, 4, "k1"),
              ("NIC", 2, 3, "k2"),
              ("NIC", 1, 1, "k3"),
              ("NIC", 7, 10, "k4")
              ).toDF("e","pd","dd", "k")
//dfD.show(false)

dfE2.createOrReplaceTempView("E2")
dfD.createOrReplaceTempView("D1")

// This done per record, if over identical keys, then strip k and aggr otherwise, I added k for checking each entry
// Point is it is far easier. Key means synthetic grouping by.

val q=sqlContext.sql(""" SELECT d1.k, d1.e, d1.pd, d1.dd, sum(e2.wh) 
                       FROM D1, E2
                      WHERE D1.e = E2.e 
                        AND E2.d >= D1.pd
                        AND E2.d <= D1.dd
                    GROUP BY d1.k, d1.e, d1.pd, d1.dd   
                    ORDER BY d1.k, d1.e, d1.pd, d1.dd
                     """)
q.show
```

returns:

```
 +---+---+---+---+-------+
 |  k|  e| pd| dd|sum(wh)|
 +---+---+---+---+-------+
 | k1|NIC|  1|  4|      2|
 | k2|NIC|  2|  3|      1|
 | k3|NIC|  1|  1|      0|
 +---+---+---+---+-------+
```

I think a simple performance improvement can be made. No correlated  stuff req'd in fact.

> Can use AND E2.d BETWEEN D1.pd AND D1.dd if you want.

Comment: No problem. You can improve performance by not showing those with 0 meaning you only record entities with weekend or holiday.