# Pyspark error while running sql subquery "AnalysisException: u"Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate:\nAggregate"

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I had written a SQL query which is has a subquery in it. It is a correct mySQL query but it does not get implemented on Pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from  pyspark.sql.functions import *
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlcontext = HiveContext(sc)
```

```
select location, postal, max(spend), max(revenue)
from (select a.*,
             (select sum(r.revenue)
              from revenue r
              where r.user = a.user and
                    r.dte >= a.dt - interval 10 minute and
                    r.dte <= a.dte + interval 10 minute
             ) as revenue
      from auction a
      where a.event in ('Mid', 'End', 'Show') and 
            a.cat_id in (3) and
            a.cat = 'B'
     ) a
group by location, postal;
```

The error eveytime I am getting is

`AnalysisException: u"Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate:\nAggregate [sum(cast(revenue#17 as double)) AS sum(CAST(revenue AS DOUBLE))#498]\n+- Filter (((user#2 = outer(user#85)) && (dt#0 >= cast(cast(outer(dt#67) - interval 10 minutes as timestamp) as string))) && ((dt#0 <= cast(cast(outer(dt#67) + interval 10 minutes as timestamp) as string))`

Any insights on this will be helpful.

Comment: Spark Currently only supports equality check try changing and remove interval part to see if it works also refer the below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004938/correlated-sub-query-column-in-spark-sql-is-not-allowed-as-part-of-a-non-equalit

Comment: @patel I had seen that question earlier, however as per spark documentation it seems it supports after Spark 3.0, that's why I asked if there is still the issue on running subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correlated subquery using sql syntax in PySpark is not an option, so in this case I ran the queries seperately with some twigs in sql query and left joined it using `df.join` to get the desired output through PySpark, this is how this issue was resolved